# Can a Wild Magic Sorcerer use Tides of Chaos to give another character advantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, wild-magic

In D&D 5e, the [Wild Magic Sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#WildMagic)'s [Tides of Chaos](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#TidesofChaos-382) feature (*PHB*, p. 103) states:

> Starting at 1st level, you can manipulate the forces of chance and chaos to gain advantage on one attack roll, ability check, or saving throw.

Can sorcerers use this feature only on rolls, checks, and throws they themselves perform, or may they use it to give another character advantage? A strict reading of the text suggests the latter, but I don't know whether that betrays the intent of the feature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No

Let’s remove the descriptive stuff from the sentence:

> Starting at 1st level, you <s>can manipulate the forces of chance and chaos to</s> gain advantage on one attack roll, ability check, or saving throw.

Who gains advantage? You do.

Comment: Thank you! And you've also illustrated a principle I don't doubt I'll find helpful in the future—remove the non-mechanical language from the text and see what's left. I'll wait a day or two before accepting, just in case, but I really appreciate it.